# Create WebComponent through createElement

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm having an issue creating a Web Component using createElement. I'm getting this error:

***Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have children
at appendTodo***

```
class TodoCard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.innerHTML = `
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                    <span class="card-content">${this.getAttribute('content')}</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        `
    }
}

window.customElements.define('todo-card', TodoCard)

const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const todoForm = document.getElementById('todo-form')
const todoInput = document.getElementById('todo-input')

function appendTodo(content) {
    const todo = document.createElement('todo-card')
    todo.setAttribute('content', content)
    todoList.appendChild(todo)
}

todoForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    appendTodo(todoInput.value)
    todoInput.value = ''
})
```

any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***A Custom Element that sets DOM content in the `constructor`

can never be created with `document.createElement()`***

You will see many examples (including from me) where DOM content is set in the constructor.
Those Elements can never be created with `document.createElement`

#### Explanation ([HTML DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API)):

When you use:

```
  <todo-card content=FOO></todo-card>
```

The element (extended from HTMLElement) has all the HTML interfaces (it is in a HTML DOM),
and you ***can*** set the innerHTML in the **constructor**

But, when you do:

```
  document.createElement("todo-card");
```

The **constructor** runs, without HTML interfaces (the element may have nothing to do with a DOM),
thus setting innerHTML in the **constructor** produces the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have children

From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance:

> The element must not gain any attributes or children, as this violates the expectations of consumers who use the createElement or createElementNS methods.
> In general, work should be deferred to connectedCallback as much as possible

### shadowDOM is a DOM

When using **shadowDOM** you *can* set **shadowDOM** content in the **constructor**:

```
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = `...`;
  }
```

### Correct code (no shadowDOM): use the `connectedCallback`:

```html
<todo-card content=FOO></todo-card>

<script>
  window.customElements.define(
    "todo-card",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        //this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("content");
      }
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("content");
      }
    }
  );

  try {
    const todo = document.createElement("todo-card");
    todo.setAttribute("content", "BAR");
    document.body.appendChild(todo);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
</script>
```

You have another minor issue: `content` **was** a default attribute, and FireFox won't stop warning you:

[image]

### Or don't use createElement

```
  const todo = document.createElement("todo-card");
  todo.setAttribute("content", "BAR");
  document.body.appendChild(todo);
```

can be written as:

```
  const html = `<todo-card content="BAR"></todo-card`;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend" , html);
```

### The `connectedCallback` can run multiple times!

When you move DOM nodes around:

```html
<div id=DO_Learn>
  <b>DO Learn: </b><todo-card todo="Custom Elements API"></todo-card>
</div>
<div id="DONT_Learn">
  <b>DON'T Learn!!! </b><todo-card todo="React"></todo-card>
</div>
<script>
  window.customElements.define(
    "todo-card",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        let txt = this.getAttribute("todo");
        this.append(txt);// and appended again on DOM moves
        console.log("qqmp connectedCallback\t", this.parentNode.id, this.innerHTML);
      }
      disconnectedCallback() {
        console.log("disconnectedCallback\t", this.parentNode.id , this.innerHTML);
      }
    }
  );
  const LIT = document.createElement("todo-card");
  LIT.setAttribute("todo", "Lit");
  DO_Learn.append(LIT);
  DONT_Learn.append(LIT);
</script>
```

- connectedCallback runs for LIT
- when LIT is moved
- disconnectedCallback runs (note the parent! The Element is already in the new location)
- connectedCallback for LIT runs again, appending `"Learn Lit"` **again**

It is up to you the programmer how your component/application must handle this

### Web Component Libraries

Libraries like Lit, HyperHTML and Hybrids have extra callbacks implemented that help with all this.

I advice to learn the Custom Elements API first, otherwise you are learning a tool and not the technology.

*And a Fool with a Tool, is still a Fool*

Also read my Dev.to post on the `connectedCallback`:
https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-developers-do-not-connect-with-the-connectedcallback-yet-4jo7

Answer (score 0):

You'r defining the custom element before inserting into the DOM, you have to follow these steps

1. create the custom element using **document.createElement("todo-card")**
2. append the created element to the DOM  using **document.body.appendChild(todo)**
3. and then finally define the custom element now using **window.customElements.define('todo-card', TodoCard)**

The below code snippet works good for me

```js
class TodoCard extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.innerHTML = `
            <li>
                <div class="card">
                    <span class="card-content">My Component</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </li>
        `
    }
}

const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list')

function appendTodo() {
    const todo = document.createElement('todo-card')
    todoList.appendChild(todo)
    window.customElements.define('todo-card', TodoCard)
}

appendTodo();
```

```html
<div id="todo-list"></div>
```