# How to use querySelector of Tags inside a Web Component

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am building an application with Web Components and only vanila javascript. I want to use vaadin-router for routing.

In my **index.html** I only display the web component `app.module`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <mp-app-root></mp-app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

the app module is a simple web component. It should display the routing module in a template. The Shadow DOM is optional.

**app.module.js**

```
import Template from './app.module.template.js'

class AppModule extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = Template.render();
    }
}

customElements.define('mp-app-root', AppModule)
```

The template simply renders the tag, where the routing should happen.

**app.module.template.js**

```
import './routing.module.js'

export default {
    render() {
        return `${this.html()}`;
    },

    html() {
        return `<script type="module" src="./routing.module.js"></script>
                <app-routing-module></app-routing-module>`;
    },
}
```

As you can see, i am importing the script `routing.module.js` - It also works, when im console.logging something

Now, I am using **vaadin-router** for routing and I want to access the `<app-routing-module>`-Tag with querySelector like this:

`const outlet = document.querySelector('mp-app-root').querySelector('app-routing-module')`

but it is always **null**.

`console.log(document.querySelector('mp-app-root')` works and prints the following:

```
<mp-app-root>
    <app-routing-module></app-routing-module>
</mp-app-root>
```

Comment: Can you try this in your browser and tell us if it works? https://jsfiddle.net/1j87xtqe/

Comment: @Guerric P yes it works. hm this is strange.

Comment: Well it might help you find the cause, I have no clue!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get `null`, in Webkit based Browsers (Safari, Chromium) because:
you **can't access the DOM it just created, in the `connectedCallback`**
The Elements DOM isn't fully parsed yet.

This is considered the correct implementation of the W3C Web Components standard

`this.innerHTML` **USED TO** have its content in FireFox, Mozilla fixed this in 2019

See:

- [How to Get the Contents of a Custom Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962138/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-custom-element)
- [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)
- [Create WebComponent through createElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066330/create-webcomponent-through-createelement/63070106#63070106)

### Correct code:

```
setTimeout( () => {
  const outlet = document.querySelector('mp-app-root')
                         .querySelector('app-routing-module')
});
```

All WebComponent libraries do something similar under the hood;
delay execution till the Eventloop is empty, and the DOM is ready to accept your selections/additions.

---

Note: `querySelector` takes a selector, so you can write:

```
  const outlet = document.querySelector('mp-app-root app-routing-module')
```